# How to print even and odd position characters of an array of strings in Java?

Tags: java, string, loops

**Question**

> *Given a string S of length N, that is indexed from 0 to N-1, print it's even indexed and odd indexed characters as 2 space separated strings on a single line.
>   Assume input starts at index position 0(which is considered even)*

**Input**

> *The first line contains an integer, T (the number of test cases). 
>   Each line i of the T subsequent lines contain a String, S.*

**Output**

> *For each string S, print it's even-indexed characters, followed by space, followed by odd-indexed characters.*

**Sample Input**

> 2
>
> Hacker
>
> Rank

**Sample Output**

> Hce akr
>
> Rn ak

**The Code I Wrote**

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner scan    =   new Scanner(System.in);
    int T   =   scan.nextInt();
    scan.nextLine();

    for(int i=0 ; i<T ; i++)
    {
        String  myString    =   scan.nextLine();

        int evn =   0,
            odd =   0,
            len =   myString.length();

        char    strE[]  =   new char[50],
                strO[]  =   new char[50];

        for(int j=0 ; j<len ; j++)
        {
            if(j%2 == 0)
            {
                strE[evn]   =   myString.charAt(j);
                evn++;
            }
            if(j%2 == 1)
            {
                strO[odd]   =   myString.charAt(j);
                odd++;
            }
        }
        System.out.print(strE);
        System.out.print(" ");
        System.out.println(strO);
    }
}
```

**My Output**

> Hce akr
>
> Rn ak

**The Problem**

> *As you can see, my program successfully meets the test case, and other test cases (using custom input) but every time the HackerRank compiler tells me that my program did not meet the test case.*
>
> *Clearly, my program is producing the required output but every time the HackerRank compiler tells me that I got the solution wrong.*
>
> **Could anyone please tell me where I am making a mistake?**

**Further Modifications**

> *I then decided to change the last 3 lines of print statements into one statement as follows:*

```
System.out.println(strE + " " + strO);
```

> *However, this time the program **did not** produce the desired output and rather printed some garbage values as follows:*
>
> [C@5c3f3b9b [C@3b626c6d
>
> [C@3abc8690 [C@2f267610

**My Doubts**

> *1. In the first case, when I was printing the two strings separately using 2 print statements, I was getting a correct output everytime but the HackerRank compiler rejected it. **Why?***
>
> *2. In the second case, when I modified the program by using one print statement instead of 3 to get the desired result, the program gave a completely different output and rather printed garbage values! **Why?***

*Here is a link to the HackerRank problem for more info:*
[hackerrank.com/challenges/30-review-loop](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/30-review-loop)

*All help and guidance is greatly appreciated and thanks a lot in advance!*

Comment: System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strE) + " " + Arrays.toString(strO));

Comment: i guess you fail the HackerRank requirements because of the empty `chars` in your arrays

Comment: @BurakAkyıldız Arrays.toString(strE) did not solve the problem. However, it did point out where I was going wrong! Turns out that the logic I applied was creating strings with a lot of empty chars. I set the char array length to the length of the original string and still I was having empty chars. Because the compiler was comparing the two strings, they did not match even though they produced the same output!  thanks :)

Comment: @XtremeBaumer yes! what you mentioned was very true! I used Arrays.toString(strE) and found that there were a lot of empty chars because of which the string comparison failed! thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int T = scan.nextInt();
```

This reads quantity of test cases, which we're going to process.

```
String string[] = new String[T];
for(int i = 0; i<T; i++){
  string[i] = scan.next();
```

}
Next we're creating an array named "string" (BTW, this a bad name for variables/objects) which has size T and in the for loop reading test cases from the input T times and saving them in the array.

```
for(int temp = 0; temp<T; temp++){
```

Now, for each of test cases we do the following...

```
for(int j = 0; j<string[temp].length(); j = j+2)
{
    System.out.print(string[temp].charAt(j));
}
```

We create a local variable j, which is visible only in this for loop. j holds index of the string (=string[temp]), which we're processing. So, we're printing a character on position j (by using standard method "charAt" of String class, which returns character of given index of the string) and then increasing it by 2. So, this code will print every even character. For string "example", it will print "eape" (j=0, j=2, j=4, j=6).

```
System.out.print(" ");
```

Separating sequences with a space.

```
for(int j = 1; j<string[temp].length(); j = j+2){
    System.out.print(string[temp].charAt(j));
}

System.out.println();
```

We're doing the same (creating index j, running though all characters of the string), but starting from "1", so it will print all odd characters of the string. For string "example", it will give you "xml" (j=1, j=3, j=5). and After this, it will end the string. I hope, it will help you to understand. :)

Answer (score 3):

Try to submit this:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int T = scan.nextInt();
scan.nextLine();
for (int i = 0; i < T; i++) {
    String myString = scan.nextLine();
    String even = "";
    String odd = "";
    for (int j = 0; j < myString.length(); j++) {
        if (j % 2 == 0) {
            even += myString.charAt(j);
        } else {
            odd += myString.charAt(j);
        }
    }

    System.out.println(even + " " + odd);
}
```

i get the right output and it should meet all the requirements. i think your code fails because its not a real string you print in the end and you have empty spots in your arrays

Comment: Yest it worked! Your solution is so much simpler than mine! I did not know that it is possible to concatenate a string in Java like you did! :) Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 2):

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the no.of test-cases:");
    int t = scanner.nextInt();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("Enter the String(s)");
    for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {

        String myString = br.readLine();
        String even = "";
        String odd = "";
        for (int j = 0; j < myString.length(); j++) {
            if (j % 2 == 0) {
                even += myString.charAt(j);
            } else {
                odd += myString.charAt(j);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(even);
        System.out.println(odd);
    }
    scanner.close();
```

Comment: Can you try explaining your code in an [edit] to make it more useful to future readers?

Comment: Concise and element. Just replace `String even` with `StringBuffer even` same with `odd` variable.

Answer (score 1):

I can solve your the second question:
---> System.out.print(strE);-->At the bottom, the method is called( public void print(char s[]));

-->System.out.println(strE + " " + strO);-->At the bottom, the method is called (public void println(String x) )

Answer (score 1):

For your first answer I am unable to answer you as I have no idea about how the compiler works, but I can answer your second question.

The reason why `System.out.print(strE); System.out.print(" "); System.out.println(strO);` works is because `System.out.print(char[])` and `System.out.println(char[])` automatically turn the char arrays into a readable string before printing it.

However, in the second case `System.out.println(strE + " " + strO);`, what you are doing is directly turning the char array into strings, which just prints the class and the hash code of the array object because the `toString()` method is not overriden in the array class. What you want to do is `System.out.println(new String(strE) + " " + new String(strO));`. It will give you the result you want.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the reason of getting random values! However, I did try your solution but still got the same result.... :( but then it turned out that my whole logic was a bit off...actually there were a lot of empty chars being added to the strE and strO strings because of which string comparison failed!

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

 private static void f(String s) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  char c[]=s.toCharArray();
  int i,j;
  for (i = 0; i <c.length;i++){ 
      System.out.print(c[i]);
      i+=1;
  }
  System.out.print(" ");
  for (j = 1; j<c.length;j++){
     System.out.print(c[j]);
     j+=1;    
  }
 }
 public static void main(String[] args){
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    int s=sc.nextInt();
    while(hasNext()){
    //for loop for multiple strings as per the input
        for(int m=0;m<= s;m++){    
          String s1=sc.next();
          f(s1); 
          System.out.println();
        }
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: it would be nice if you add some explanation for your code

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this question in 2 ways & both are producing correct output.

Have a look & let me know if you've any problem.

1. Instead of using char array, you can use String

   ```
    //char[] even = new char[10000];
    String even = "";
   ```

Let's look at the code

```
private static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); 

public static void main(String[] args) {

        String s = scanner.next();

        char[] array = s.toCharArray();

        int count=0;            
        //char[] even = new char[10000];
        //char[] odd = new char[10000];
        String even = "";
        String odd = "";
        for(char ch : array){

            if(count%2 == 0){
                even = even + ch;
            }else{
                odd = odd + ch;
            }
            count++;
        }
        count = 0;

        System.out.println(even + " " + odd);
}
```

Output:

```
  hacker
  hce akr
```

2. No need of extra char[] or String to store even & odd position characters, we can directly print them using appropriate condition.

   ```
   private static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); 

   public static void main(String[] args){

       String s = scanner.next();

       char[] array = s.toCharArray();

       int count=0;

       for(char ch : array){

           if(count%2 == 0){
               System.out.print(ch);
           }
           count++;
       }
       count = 0;
       System.out.print(" ");
       for(char ch : array){

           if(count%2 != 0){
               System.out.print(ch);
           }
           count++;
       }
       count = 0;
   }
   ```

Output:

```
  hacker
  hce akr
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Enter string to check:");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String T = scan.nextLine();
    String even = "";
    String odd = "";
    for (int j = 0; j < T.length(); j++) {
        if (j % 2 == 0) { //check the position of the alphabet by dividing it by 0
            even += T.charAt(j);
        } else {
            odd += T.charAt(j);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(even + " " + odd);

    scan.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
** JavaScript version **

function processData(input) {
   for (let i = 1; i < input.length; i++) {
     printOutput(input[i]);
   }
}

function printOutput(input) {
  var result = [];
  input.length % 2 == 0 ? result[input.length / 2] = ' ': result[Math.ceil(input.length / 2)] = ' ';
  for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
        result[i / 2] = input[i];
    }
    else {
        result[Math.ceil(input.length / 2) + Math.ceil(i / 2)] = input[i];
    }
}
console.log(result.join(''));
}

process.stdin.on("end", function () {
processData(_input.split('\n'));

});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.io. * ;
import java.util. * ;

public class Solution {
String myString;
public Solution(String myString) {
    this.myString = myString;
    int len = myString.length();
    for (int j = 0; j < len; j++) {
        if (j % 2 == 0) {
            System.out.print(myString.charAt(j));
        }
    }
    System.out.print(" ");
    for (int j = 0; j < len; j++) {

        if (j % 2 == 1) {
            System.out.print(myString.charAt(j));
        }
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT. Your class should be named Solution. */
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System. in );
    int T = sc.nextInt();
    for (int i = 0; i < T; i++) {
        String word = sc.next();
        Solution sol = new Solution(word);
        System.out.println();
    }
    sc.close();
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int T;
        T = s.nextInt();
        String[] str = new String[T];
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<T;i++) {
            str[i] = s.next();
        }    
        for(i=0;i<T;i++) {
            char[] even = new char[5000];
            char[] odd = new char[5000];
            int ev =0,od=0;
            for(int j= 0;j< str[i].length();j++) {
                if(j%2== 0) {
                    even[ev] = str[i].charAt(j);
                    ev++;
                }else {
                    odd[od] = str[i].charAt(j);
                    od++;
                }
            }
            String strEven = new String(even);
            String strOdd = new String(odd);
           System.out.print(strEven.trim());
           System.out.print(" ");
           System.out.println(strOdd.trim());

        }
        s.close();
    }
}
```

I am sure that this will work You've forgotten to convert it to a string and also increase the size of the character array

Answer (score 1):

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan= new Scanner(System.in);
        int n= scan.nextInt();
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            String s= scan.next();
            int len= s.length();
            StringBuffer str_e= new StringBuffer();
            StringBuffer str_o= new StringBuffer();
            for(int j=0;j<len;j++){
                if(j%2==0)
                    str_e= str_e.append(s.charAt(j));
                if(j%2==1)
                    str_o= str_o.append(s.charAt(j));
            }
            System.out.println(str_e+" "+str_o);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Code only answers considered low quality

Comment: The question was why the threadstarters code failed not what a possible solution is

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT. Your class should be named Solution. */
        Scanner pp=new Scanner(System.in);
        int n=pp.nextInt();

        for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            String ip=pp.next();
            String re1="",
                    re2="";
            for(int j=0; j<ip.length(); j++)
            {
                if(j%2 == 0)
                {
                    re1+= ip.charAt(j);
                }
                if(j%2 == 1)
                {
                    re2+= ip.charAt(j);        
                }
            }
              System.out.print(re1+" "+re2);     
            System.out.println("");    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. Additionally, it usually isn't beneficial to answer three year old questions unless your answer includes relevant new information.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class PrintCharacters{

public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    int noOfTestCases = sc.nextInt();
    sc.nextLine();
    String []inputStrings= new String[noOfTestCases];
    for(int i=0;i<noOfTestCases;i++) {
        inputStrings[i]=sc.nextLine();
    }
    
    for(String str: inputStrings) {
        String even ="";
        String odd ="";
        for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++) {
            if(i%2==0) {
                even+=str.charAt(i);
            }else {
                odd+=str.charAt(i);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(even+" "+odd);
    }
    sc.close();
    
}

}


Input: 
  2
  Hacker
  Rank

Output:
  Hce akr
  Rn ak
```

Answer (score 1):

import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT. Your class should be named Solution. */
    
    Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
    int n=scan.nextInt();
    while(n>0) {
        String str=scan.next();
        for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++) {
            if(i%2==0) {
                System.out.print(str.charAt(i));
            }
        }
        System.out.print(" ");
        for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++) {
            if(i%2==1) {
                System.out.print(str.charAt(i));
            }
        }
        n--;
        System.out.println();
    }
    
    
}
```

}

Comment: Whats your concrete question? What have you tried out? What does not work as you expect it to work?